# Bluebird Execute array of promises in series

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm trying to do the following function.

1. Write file
2. Send an email with the file attached
3. Delete the file

I'm doing the code below but when I receive the email, the file has the ENOENT content.
When I remove the variable removeFile I receive the email with all the content that I requested. 
I've tried with Promise.reduce too, but with no luck either. 
What I'm doing wrong?

```
var writeFile = fs.writeFileAsync(filePath, csv)
var sendMail = sendEmail(to, from, msg, subject, fileName, filePath)
var removeFile = fs.unlinkAsync(filePath)
  return Promise.each([writeFile, sendMail, removeFile], function(fn){
    return fn
})
```

Comment: You start the action when you create the promise, not when you call `Promise.each` upon it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To serialize operations, you need to NOT call them until it is their turn.  Your assigment to `writeFile`, `sendMail` and `removeFile` is calling all their functions immediately which is definitely not what you want.

Assuming `sendMail()` is synchronous, then you need to chain your promises:

```
fs.writeFileAsync(filePath, csv).then(sendMail).then(function() {
    return fs.unlinkAsync(filePath);
}).then(function() {
    // everything done successfully here
}, function(err) {
    // some sort of error here
});
```

If `sendMail()` is not synchronous, then you need a callback or a promise from it so you can tell when it's done so it will chain asynchrously.